# Dimension of a nullmatrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I have the following problem:
I have to find the null vector and dimension of $\mathbb R^{4x2}$.
I know  the null vector of it is:
$$\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\\0&0\\0&0\\\end{bmatrix}$$
I would say the dimension was 2 because there are two vectors, but my book says the answer is 8. I don't understand that. Is the answer simply $4\cdot2=8$?

Comment: How many linearly independent elements do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dimension is $8$ because you have eight entries to fill. A basis of this space is$$\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\\0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\\0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\\0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\\0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\\1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\\0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\\0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\\0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\right\}.$$

Comment: So a 4x3 matrix would have a dimension of 12?

Comment: @asdfjkl No. The *space of all* $4\times3$ matrices has dimension $12$.